# _JAVA_OPTIONS and CLASSPATH combination

Tags: java, classpath, agent

I try to attach an agent to a program.

I use _JAVA_OPTIONS for the following:

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS='-javaagent:/java/libs/doeke_sfjl_ui/sfjl_ui_widget_agent.jar'
```

But it needs a jar file in order to run.
I tried solving that by using:

```
export CLASSPATH=/java/libs/javassist-3.26.0.GA/javassist-3.26.0.GA.jar
```

But I still get a:

> ClassNotFoundException: javassist.expr.ExprEditor

Which lives in `javassist-3.26.0.GA.jar`.

How can I add `javassist-3.26.0.GA.jar` before the agent is running?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47948300/specifying-the-classpath-for-a-java-agent might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various different ways things are going wrong here:

1. You should avoid these environment variables. The idea behind java is that you may well run 8 different apps at the same time. Especially on windows, environment variables are 'global'; you can specify them per-process especially on unix, but then why aren't you just using the switches by hand? Also, the vast majority of tutorials etc out there presume that your default classpath at the very least includes `.` (the current dir), which your attempt here overrides, so you're kinda messing up your java install by doing this. Is there a good reason for why you can't just run `java -cp whatever -javaagent:thingie.jar`?
2. java agents run in a separate space within the VM, and that space does not get the enjoy the classpath as you specified it. The easiest fix is to have the agent jar fix its own classpath, by shipping with a manifest entry listing its Class-Path. This means you need a file named `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` inside the agent jar, and inside is a line of text reading: `Boot-Class-Path: lib/a.jar lib/b.jar` where [1] space is the separator, [2] forward slashes are used to separate path parts, even on windows, and [3] it is relative to the directory containing this jar. Note, normally you'd use `Class-Path:` for a java app; `Boot-Class-Path` is specifically for java agents.

See [section Manifest Attributes in Instrumentation's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) for more details.

Comment: @1 I'm starting a new shell before doing this so the rest of the environment is not affected. I can't run `java -cp whatever -javaagent:thingie.java` because the file is a executable.
@2 The `Boot-Class-Path` worked, but the amount of errors I get are so many that I will look into a different approach.